# customize KDE system tray's icons

Tags: icons, kde, system-tray, icon-themes

I would like to replace default icons in KDE's system tray with my some other icons by my own.

I use Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.
File structure should be the same, but I didn't test if it works.
https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-custom-tray-icons-in-kde/

Comment: I dont have KDE any more so I cannot test.